# how to get current visible substring from long animated-moving string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, banner, uiviewanimation

In a long animated-moving string from right to left, I want to get actually visible substring. Is it possible to get it in an animation process?

I must keep two features of the banner:

1. smooth moving
2. get substring (few characters) in some point on the screen

It is long string in one line.

I use this animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:10.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

...

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I tried with:

CGPoint currentPosition = [[self.autoScrollText.layer presentationLayer] position];

but unsuccessfully...

Comment: You want to control the text position, relative to the banner--which is a UIView, and which is moving?

Comment: @iPadDeveloper2011  banner is UITextView which is subview of ScrollView

Comment: @escape321.  OK, so you _don't_ want to move your text, relative to the banner, you just want to change the text in the banner? like: "..."->"lo..."->"ello..."->"hello..."?

Comment: BTW a UITextView _is a_ UIScrollView, which _is a_ UIView (UITextView is a _type_ of UIScrollView which is a type of UIView).  UITextView _is not_ a subview of UIScrollView, it is a _subclass_.

Comment: @escape321.  Please reformulate/clarify your question.  As is, it is a bad/unclear question which deserves to be voted down.

Comment: @iPadDeveloper2011 I did some changes on my question...I hope it is more clear now..

Comment: @escape321.  No, it is still not clear.  If you want a substring of an `NSString`, you should use methods like `substringFromIndex, substringToIndex`, and `substringWithRange`.  The fact that it is animated/moving is irrelevant.

Comment: @iPadDeveloper2011  It is long animated-moving string from right to left, and i want to get actually visible substring.I think index and range doesn't help here...

Comment: which property of the UITextView do you animate? I guess the frame's origin ...

Comment: @phix23 currently I use AutoScrollLabel Created by Brian Stormont on Copyright 2009 Stormy Productions....which is UITextField *label

Comment: @phix23 this is piece of his scroll function:

[UIView setAnimationDuration:label[0].frame.size.width/(float)scrollSpeed];
 
 if (scrollDirection == AUTOSCROLL_SCROLL_LEFT){
  self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(label[0].frame.size.width+LABEL_BUFFER_SPACE,0);
 }else{
  self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);
 }  
 
 [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: @escape321 "It is long animated-moving string from right to left, and i want to get actually visible substring." This should be in your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

If your text is in a standard width font, like Courier, you could do this by relating the position of your `UITextView`, the width of your characters, and the LHS and RHS of your viewport.

Comment: In the beginning was Currier, and everything was easy when I moved frame.x from left to right...I had the absolute control and any substring what I want....but font is ugly and moving frame by pixel is not smooth.So, now I have animation and Helvetica font...is any hope for my case?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a *heuristic*.  I guess you are doing a number (`i`) of different things depending on which string is "visible" when the user clicks a button. Precisely which of these things ultimately depends on the origin (`x` position) of your text string.  Instead of working this out programatically, work it out yourself (through observation/trial and error) and select between the `i` different options based on the ranges of `x` that you determine.

Comment: I guess [this SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324379/how-to-calculate-the-width-of-a-text-string-of-a-specific-font-and-font-size) may help also.