# How to fill a label with text until it reaches it's width

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to know if there is a way to determine if a `UILabel` is *full* of text.
For example, if a have a label with size of:

```
|         |
```

I want to know when the label is full of text, such as:

```
|.........|
```

I need to fill its with dots until it reaches the textFields width.

Comment: You can get the label width and the width of the text (via https://stackoverflow.com/q/1324379/2442804 ) and compare the two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, If I got it right, probably what are you looking for is Label [intrinsicContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize:):

> The natural size for the receiving view, considering only properties
>   of the view itself.

the width of the label `intrinsicContentSize` should be the actual width of the label, doesn't matter what's the `frame.size.width` value.

Based on that, you simply implement:

```
let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 21))

print(lbl.frame.size.width)
// 150.0

lbl.text = ""

let intrinsicSizeWidth = lbl.intrinsicContentSize.width
// since the label text is still empty, its value should be 0.0

print(intrinsicSizeWidth)

while lbl.intrinsicContentSize.width < lbl.frame.size.width {
    lbl.text?.append(".")
}

print(lbl.text!)
// ................................
```

Note that increasing your label width would leads to contains more dots:

```
let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))

.
.
.

print(lbl.text!)
// ...........................................
```

Obviously, if you would like to compare it with a `UITextField` -for instance- (as you mentioned in the question), it should be:

```
// "textField" the name of your text field...
while lbl.intrinsicContentSize.width < textField.frame.size.width {
    lbl.text?.append(".")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create label with frame and default text

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 100))
label.text = ""
```

Populate text with dots until text's width reaches label's width

```
while label.sizeThatFits(label.frame.size).width <= label.frame.width {
    label.text = label.text! + "."
}
```