# How to stop label in long text?

Tags: swift, user-interface

I'm trying to layout my UI. I want to do something like this: 
[image]

I want the label gonna stop if it meet another view like heart button in this case 
Is there any way or trick to do this ? Thank you so much.

Comment: What exact behavior do you want? Shrink the text if it's out of room? Just hide the ellipsis? Continue onto another line?

Comment: I want the text shrink, but notice that in the example image, first line still continue because it is above of the button

Comment: See [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+wrap+text+around) for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly what you need to do is:

1: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39904016/4757272) to calculate the width of the text lines.

2: Set a line height and line spacing

3: Get label top frame position add each row of text (height + spacing) and see if it intercepts the `UIButton`'s frame and in that case truncate the line if line is greater than `label.minX` position - `button.minX` position

I have never done this myself. And as i'm not actually giving you a solution this is not the correct answer. But this is the approach i would have.

Good luck.

**Edit:**
As **@Maddy** mentioned, the `exclusionPaths` might work. But if you strive for truncating it i don't know if that is the correct approach.