# How to truncate UILabel and leave specifically x trailing characters?

Tags: swift, uilabel

Examples (x=1):

```
ABC -> ABC
ABCDEFGHIJKL -> ABCDE...L
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS -> ABCDE...S
```

(truncating after 5 characters is an arbitrary choice for this question - it will depend on the width of the label of course)

I'm basically looking for the same functionality as truncating in the middle, but where I can specify how many characters to leave on the trailing end. Is this available in Swift or is there  a reasonable workaround?

Comment: Well it isn't built in or anything like that. If you want to just change the string to substitute dots where you want them, then that's up to you.

Comment: Yes, I could. However, how would I determine "where I want them" given strings with varying lengths?

Comment: You can measure the string (i.e. in pixel width)

Comment: After almost an hour, I am failing to translate this to code. Care to give a hint on how to start (words or code)?

Comment: For example https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrect and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1531844-size ?

Comment: You can get a lot more sophisticated by drawing with TextKit. But basically whatever you do here, you are rolling your own; what you ask for is not built in

Answer (score 1):

You can [measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324379/how-to-calculate-the-width-of-a-text-string-of-a-specific-font-and-font-size/52378302#52378302) any string with `.size(withAttributes:)` function. Where attributes is your font.

Here is the idea:

1. get length of the last x characters plus dots symbol
2. iteratively measure the string starting from the beginning and adding 1 char on each step
3. if width of the leading string plus tail excess the given width, take just the string from the previous step.

Comment: what about labels with multiple lines?

Comment: Consider this method 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrectwithsize